# Raspbian@RPi3 is unsuccessful to boot up with SenseHAT

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

My raspberry pi is installed with the latest raspbian image, and now I am trying to program my SenseHAT. The status is :

- The firmware boots up successfully, the rainbow is displayed on the
  screen and Sense HAT, and it proceeds.
- The OS(up-to-date raspbian) start loading with the splash screen, but
  it is stuck at somewhere when it says udisks2.service,
- All the OS modules are installed,
- I2C is enabled at /boot/config.txt
- dt_overlay is configured at /boot/config.txt.

Anybody has faced this freezing problem before? My raspberry pi 3 and Sense HAT simply not getting along with each other.

Comment: The senseHAT light turn on boot? If yes, rainbow pattern or white?

You need a good power adapter (at least 2A), check that too.

Comment: Yep, it passes the rainbow check.And I am using my samsung fast charging adapter.

Comment: I suppose you don't have the same problem without the hat. Some time, the udisks2 service takes a long time on boot, up to 1 minute on normal desktop pc. Keep in mind, that's not a normal behavior. But, because the RiP3 is pretty slow, probably it's not actually stuck, but need maybe 2-3 minute or more to complete the job and continue the boot.

Comment: I will give it a try, yet I don't see any activity on the IO light.